# findAndModify query not executing in callback to aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have an aggregation query on a students collection that is returning two sets of results
for each student like this

```
{ _id: 1543,
  name: 'Bill Jackson',
  scores: { type: 'homework', score: 38.86823689842918 } }

{ _id: 1543,
  name: 'Bill Jackson',
  scores: { type: 'homework', score: 15.861613903793295 } }
```

That's working fine. Now in the callback I want to remove one of the scores for each student. I use ugly nested conditionals below to isolate which of the two records I want to remove, and, once that's achieved I create a find and Modify query to remove the doc but there's no evidence of it getting run.   Neither the error or success callback to the findAndModify are getting run, however I am able to log that I'm inside the area where the findAndModify is getting called.

Is it possible to query the db in the callback to an aggregation? If not, how should I perform an operation that persists in the db?

```
                              //aggregation query ommitted
  , function(err, result) {   //callbackstarts here with result of aggregation query that returns two records for each student


   for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {

    var id = result[i]['_id'];

    if (id === result[i]['_id']){
        if (foo && foo === result[i]['_id']){
         //if we're in here, we know we need to remove score associated with this result[i]['_id']

          //create findAndModify to remove the record
                var query = { '_id' : result[i]['_id']}
                var sort = []
                var operation = { '$pull' : { 'scores.score' : result[i]['scores']['score'] } };
                var options = []

                console.log('this code is getting called but findAndModify not')

                db.collection('students').findAndModify(query, sort, operation, options,function(err, doc) {
                            if(err) throw err;

                            if (!doc) {
                                console.log("record not found");
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("changed doc" + doc);
                            }


                        });

        }else {

          var foo = result[i]['_id']  //part of logic to isolate which of two records to remove


           }
```

Comment: Are you by any chance doing the MongoDB course??

Comment: yes, I am. Just to be clear for anyone concerned I might be cheating, my question is not asking for the solution to the homework, just to explain a problem I encountered (why isn't query in callback running) while I tried to solve the homework.